# Make part name uppercase with lower case part number in toc (KOMA)

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, parts

I tried to change the part name in the toc to upper case letter but unfortunately it doesn't work. Has someone an idea how to change the title to upper case but to set the partnumber to lower case(in the normalfont) without effecting the partpage?

```
\documentclass[             final,
                            fontsize=12pt,              
                            open=right,         
                             twoside = true,
                             paper=a4,              
                             listof=totoc,      
                             captions=tableheading,
                                listof=totoc,       
                             numbers=noenddot,
                             headings=big,
                             chapterprefix=false]   % 
                            {scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalsize\scshape}
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily} 
\addtokomafont{section}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}     
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries\scshape\lowercase}
\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\normalfont\normalcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}


%Part
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=1.1em]{part} 
\RedeclareSectionCommand[innerskip=0mm]{part} 
\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
\setkomafont{part}{\large\color{red}\scshape\MakeUppercase} 
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\large}

\setkomafont{partentry}{\color{red}\scshape%\MakeUppercase
    }   %%?????
\setkomafont{partentrypagenumber}{\normalfont\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman} 
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures                  
    \listoftables   
    \newpage 
    \pagenumbering{arabic} 
    \part{Stuff}
    \blinddocument  
    \part{More Stuff}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think  setting and adding and patching LaTeX code to get the same input output with capital letters on different places is a waste of time. Just input the tiles Uppercased.

Comment: The problem is if I refer to a part, chapter etc. by name in the text, it will be uppercase, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I did not understand how the part number should be formatted. But you can redefine `\addparttocentry`:

```
\renewcommand\addparttocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{\protect\lowercase{#1}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{#2}}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  final,
  fontsize=12pt,
  open=right,
  twoside = true,
  paper=a4,
  listof=totoc,
  captions=tableheading,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot,
  headings=big,
  chapterprefix=false]
  {scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{section}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries\scshape\lowercase}
\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\normalfont\normalcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%Part
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocnumwidth=1.1em,
  innerskip=0mm
  ]{part} 

\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
\setkomafont{part}{\large\color{red}\scshape\MakeUppercase} 
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\large}
\renewcommand\addparttocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{\protect\lowercase{#1}}{\protect\MakeUppercase{#2}}}
\setkomafont{partentry}{\color{red}\scshape}
\setkomafont{partentrypagenumber}{\normalfont\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman} 
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \cleardoubleoddpage 
    \pagenumbering{arabic} 
    \part{Stuff}
    \blinddocument  
    \part{More Stuff}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that you have to use `\cleardoubleoddpage` before `\pagenumbering{arabic}` to ensure that there is a left (even) page before page 1. (In your example page v was followed by page 1).

Additionally element `sectioning` is only an alias for element `dispostion`.

---

**Update**

With package `hyperref` use:

```
\renewcommand\addparttocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{\protect\lowercase{#1}}{%
    \protect\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  final,
  fontsize=12pt,
  open=right,
  twoside = true,
  paper=a4,
  listof=totoc,
  captions=tableheading,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot,
  headings=big,
  chapterprefix=false]
  {scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{section}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries\scshape\lowercase}
\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\normalfont\normalcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%Part
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocnumwidth=1.1em,
  innerskip=0mm
  ]{part} 

\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
\setkomafont{part}{\large\color{red}\scshape\MakeUppercase} 
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\large}
\renewcommand\addparttocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{\protect\lowercase{#1}}{%
    \protect\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}}
\setkomafont{partentry}{\color{red}\scshape}
\setkomafont{partentrypagenumber}{\normalfont\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman} 
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \cleardoubleoddpage 
    \pagenumbering{arabic} 
    \part{Stuff}
    \blinddocument  
    \part{More Stuff}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution -- it seems that the `hyperref`-package is breaking it, is there a way to make it work with `hyperref`?

Comment: @harryhaller Check that `hyperref` is loaded last of your packages.

Comment: @Sveinung Even with `hyperref` at the bottom of my header file -- i get the message that "\part ist undefined"    part I.
! Undefined control sequence.
\MakeUppercase ...ppercaseUnsupportedInPdfStrings 
                                                  
l.54  \part{Stuff}
                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: @harryhaller See my updated answer.

Comment: I changed `\MakeUppercase` to `\uppercase` and it seems to work, too. Is there a reason to use `Makeuppercase` inseatd od `uppercase`?, Thanks for your solution:)

Comment: @harryhaller See http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-casechange.html